# Setting envrionment variables using Rubber while deploying a Rails app on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, capistrano

N00b question here, but I am currently deploying my Rails webapp on my EC2 server instance using rubber. I was previously deploying on heroku (got frustrated with how slow it was on each startup) and decided to switch hosts last night.

There are a few environment variables I'd like to set upon deploying (for stripe). In my heroku case, I was able to just set the environment variables at the command line using something like:

```
heroku set ENV_VAR1=xxxxyyyyzzzz ENV_VAR2=xxxxyyyyzzzz
```

I was wondering if there was either a cap command, or some file I could alter to set those evironment vars on EC2, or even a command from the command line I could run to set them? I am not super familiar with rubber / cap, as I was just following one of the rails cast videos last night.

Thanks everyone.